# Time data does not match format (should be)

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, strptime

I'm unpacking some data from a file, and some of the birthdates has different formats. I need to check if the dates has the right format, and then change them to the right format.

So, here is my code:

```
   name, birthdate, residence, gender = line.split('|')
   try:
    birthdate == datetime.strptime(birthdate, '%y/%m/%d')
   except ValueError:
    print("Wrong format!")

   birthdates_list.append(birthdate)
```

And then:

```
for birthdates in birthdates_list:
  if birthdates == datetime.strptime(birthdates, '%y/%m/%d'):
    pass
  else:
    print("Wrong format!")
```

But i get the error:

```
Wrong format!

File ".\dates.py", line 47, in <module>
if birthdates = datetime.strptime(birthdates, '%y/%m/%d'):
File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '1978/05/17' does not match format '%y/%m/%d'
```

1978/05/17 is the exact same format as %y/%m/%d, so why does it say that?

Comment: *"1978/05/17 is the exact same format as %y/%m/%d"* - nope, `%y` would match `'78'`, not `'1978'`; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1978/05/17 is the exact same format as %y/%m/%d" - nope, %y would match '78', not '1978'; see docs.python.org/3/library/…. – jonrsharpe

Thanks!

It worked! Onto the next thing, what would be the best way to force the other dates (which is not in that format, suddenly %d/%m/%Y) to the format %Y/%m/%d?